# SKSpriteNode in scene editor not using assigned custom class

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit

I'm using Xcode 8.3.3.

I made a custom "Platform" class for some platforms. This is the first time I'm trying to use a custom class on a sprite made in the scene editor and for some reason the sprite just isn't using it.

It seems pretty cut and dry, I setup a sprite with default settings in the scene editor, then set the custom class designator like this (a screen cap of my actual project):[image]

Here is the actual class:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class Platform: SKSpriteNode {

init() {

    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "blue_button01")

    super.init(texture: texture, color: SKColor.clear, size: texture.size())

    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: texture.size())
    physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.platform.rawValue
    physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.player.rawValue
    physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.player.rawValue
    physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    setScale(2)
    zPosition = 2
    physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}



}
```

There are no errors it runs and complies fine, but when the game loads it loads a red sprite with default settings. I am expecting it to load the sprite with the settings of the "Platform.swift: class but it doesn't.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

(I'm aware of other methods to lay out levels, but I really like laying out the basics in the scene editor and then customizing everything in code.)

EDIT:

My end goal for my project's work flow is to open the .sks and place sprites where i want them, how large i want them, and what texture I want them to use, for example with selected blue platform here in the screenshot in the .sks I would place it like so:[image]

Then with my custom class I want to set up all the other requirements for the platform like collision bit masks, linear dampening, rotation, etc.

then after the custom class is applied I want to reference and use the sprite with it's custom class applied in my gamescene.swift file to setup things like movement actions.

Answer (score 4):

When your sprite node is initialised from the `.sks` file, the `init` that you defined is not called. Instead, it calls the `init(coder:)` initializer. You should set up your sprite in this initializer:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    texture = SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Spaceship"))
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "blue_button01")
    self.texture = texture
    color = .clear
    size = texture.size()
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: texture.size())
    physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.platform.rawValue
    physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.player.rawValue
    physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.player.rawValue
    physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    setScale(2)
    zPosition = 2
    physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
}
```

Comment: Thank you! your solution is partially working. My goal is to place the position and texture of the sprite in the .sks file and do everything else in it's custom class.  In your solution I removed lines 3-8 from the class thinking it would now pull the texture,position, and sizing information from the .sks file. when I load the simulator the size, position, and scale of the sprite does not match the .sks scene. its way off.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you edit your question to explain what you expected to see and what you did see? @genericguy25